# Jenkins Github Enterprise Oauth Issues

Tags: jenkins, github-api

Trying to get jenkins set up with github enterprise oauth and im getting a 500 error after allowing authorization. Not sure where to start, or how to even disable it temporarily to fix the issue...

```
Status Code: 500

Exception: no protocol: oururl.net/user?access_token=afbbb0e1eae4a22da6e06ac18bc72f51bebbd875
Stacktrace:
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: oururl.net/user?access_token=afbbb0e1eae4a22da6e06ac18bc72f51bebbd875
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getApiURL(GitHub.java:178)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:139)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getMyself(GitHub.java:203)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.<init>(GitHub.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.connectUsingOAuth(GitHub.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthenticationToken.<init>(GithubAuthenticationToken.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubSecurityRealm.doFinishLogin(GithubSecurityRealm.java:315)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:203)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:583)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:214)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:64)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:227)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Generated by Stapler at Fri May 31 21:49:31 UTC 2013
```

Comment: I've encountered similar issues when setting up auth with the basic GitHub plugin. At least to start... 

1. To disable , edit config.xml directly e.g.

>vi /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml

and set

    <useSecurity>false</useSecurity>

this will at least turn it auth off so you can get back to the Jenkins site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-oauth-plugin/pull/11 suggests that there is a fix for this issue but it hasn't been merged yet.  Not sure how they advertised this feature as working before.  Odd.